# Issue with Mastermind Game in C language

Tags: c

I've been trying for a while to make this work but I'm still stuck with some issue...I would love some help.

The thing is the code works almost the way I want, the only issue I have is when the program is telling you how many colours you guessed right, if the first colour matches it works good but if the others positions are right the program give a wrong answer (or at least not what I would like).

I'm just starting to code I know my code is really far from being perfect.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_STRING 4
#define SIZE_STRING_BIG 15

void randomSeed(){
srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) ); 
}

int randomM(int nMin, int nMax){
return nMin + rand()%(nMax-nMin+1);
}


int main(){

randomSeed();

char szUser[SIZE_STRING_BIG];
char szP[6]={'Y','B','W','P','R','G'}, szComputer[SIZE_STRING_BIG] = {szP[randomM(0,5)], szP[randomM(0,5)], szP[randomM(0,5)], szP[randomM(0,5)], '\0'};
int counter=0;
int colour=0;
int position=0; 

printf("\n\n MASTERMIND ");
printf("\n\n We'll play with this colours:");
printf("\n\n Y - Yellow    B - Blue     W - White");
printf("\n P - Purple    R - Red      G - Green");
printf("\n\n You have 8 changes to get t right. \n");   

printf(" Machine choose %s", szComputer); // this line just to check everything works allright

do{
    counter++;
    position=0;
    colour=0;
    printf("\n ===================================================\n");
    printf("\n Chance %d", counter);
    printf("\n\n Please add your 4 colours ");
    printf("\n (Please write the four capital letters without space)  ");       
    scanf("%s",szUser);     

    if(strlen(szUser) != SIZE_STRING)
    {
        printf("\n\n Sorry you choose a wrong option.");
        counter--;
    } else {

            if(strcmp(szUser,szComputer))
            {
                printf("\n Wrong choice. Try again...");                    

                if (szUser[0] == szComputer[0])
                {
                    position++;
                }
                if (szUser[1] == szComputer[1])
                {
                    position++;
                }
                if (szUser[2] == szComputer[2])
                {
                    position++;
                }
                if (szUser[3] == szComputer[3])
                {
                    position++;
                }   

                printf("\n\n You have %d in the right position", position);

                if ( szUser[0] == szComputer[0] || szUser[0] == szComputer[1] || szUser[0] == szComputer[2] || szUser[0] == szComputer[3] )
                {
                    colour++;
                }                   
                if ( szUser[1] == szComputer[1] || szUser[1] == szComputer[2] || szUser[1] == szComputer[3] )
                {
                    colour++;
                }                   
                if ( szUser[2] == szComputer[2] || szUser[2] == szComputer[3] )
                {
                    colour++;
                }                   
                if ( szUser[3] == szComputer[3] )
                {
                    colour++;
                }

                printf("\n You have %d colours right\n", colour);
            }
        }

}while(strcmp(szUser,szComputer) && counter <=7);

if (strcmp(szUser,szComputer))
{
    printf("\n\n Sorry, you run out of chances...");
}   

if(!strcmp(szUser,szComputer))
    printf("\n\n Right choice !\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Is it the colours correct count? I think you need to compare every combination of colours right, not just the triangle you've got. e.g. you never compare szUser[3] against szComputer[0]. You possibly need to account for duplicate colours at each end too, e.g. if szUser[0] == szUser[1] but both only match szComputer[1] and no other szComputer then you'll still report two colours correct when there's only one match really.

Comment: Please show some sets of input, wrong output, desired output.

Comment: i dont know how to debug :(

Comment: Maybe there's a better algorithm, but this is the one that springs to mind for me. To work out how many colours you've got correct: for each colour in szP, count the number of that colour in User and Computer and then the number correct of that colour is the minimum of those two. Sum across all colours. You should also try and do the `position++` check with a for loop if you can.

Comment: Do you have an IDE or a debugging tool you can use to set breakpoints or step through the program and see what the state is at each point? Or you could try adding in extra printfs (like you did for the computer's choice) e.g. in each of the `colour++` checks, identifying which of the tests this is and maybe the new value of colour after incrementing it.

Comment: if ( szUser[0] == szComputer[0] || szUser[0] == szComputer[1] || szUser[0] == szComputer[2] || szUser[0] == szComputer[3] ) if ( szUser[1] == szComputer[0] || szUser[1] == szComputer[1] || szUser[1] == szComputer[2] || szUser[1] == szComputer[3] ) if ( szUser[2] == szComputer[0] || szUser[2] == szComputer[1] || szUser[2] == szComputer[2] || szUser[2] == szComputer[3] ) if ( szUser[3] == szComputer[0] || szUser[3] == szComputer[1] || szUser[3] == szComputer[2] || szUser[3] == szComputer[3] ) instead of the triangle i used this 4 lines but now i got 4 colours right anytime i got just 1

Comment: im gonna give some thought to what you said, thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using another array to keep track of which of the computer's pegs you've already seen for the current turn of the game:

```
char seen[SIZE_STRING];
```

For each turn, reset the "seen" flags and the count of correct colour and position pegs, and the count of correct colour and wrong position pegs:

```
memset(seen, 0, sizeof(seen));
position = 0;
colour = 0;
```

Then count user pegs with the correct colour and position, marking them as seen:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_STRING; i++)
{
    if (szUser[i] == szComputer[i])
    {
        seen[i] = 1;
        position++;
    }
}
```

Then count user pegs with the same colour as computer pegs that haven't been seen yet, marking the matching computer pegs as seen. These user pegs will all be at the wrong position because pegs of the correct colour at the correct position have already been accounted for above:

**EDIT 1: My original version of the inner loop could count a user peg more than once if several computer pegs had the same colour as the user peg. I have added a `break;` statement to the inner loop to fix this so that each user peg can match at most one computer peg.**

**EDIT 2: The outer loop also needs to skip over any user pegs that matched in the position matching loop to avoid counting them twice.**

```
for (int u = 0; u < SIZE_STRING; u++)
{
    // Bug fix (EDIT 2).  Skip user pegs already accounted for by position matching loop ...
    if (szUser[u] == szComputer[u])
    {
        // Already accounted for this user peg.
        continue;
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < SIZE_STRING; c++)
    {
        if (!seen[c] && szUser[u] == szComputer[c])
        {
            colour++;
            seen[c] = 1;
            // Bug fix (EDIT 1) due to comment by @Rup ...
            break; // Skip to next user peg.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks sensible, but I think if I guess `YY..` and the answer is `..Y.` then you'll count both Ys as a correct colour in the wrong place when I think you should only count one. Which you could solve by another 'seen' for the computer's choices I suppose.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had that backwards: my example needs to be I guess `Y...` and the answer is `.YY.` and then you'll return 2 not 1.

Comment: @Rup Yes, I see what you mean, but I think the problem can be solved by breaking out of the inner loop when a match is found.

Comment: Yep, neat, that would do it! (Or maybe it needs to be the outer loop?)

Comment: @Rup As it turns out, I need an additional bit of code in the outer loop to skip those user pegs that already matched colour and position in the earlier position-checking loop, otherwise the same user peg could be counted as both correct colour / correct position, and as correct colour / wrong position for a different computer peg.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying with the code you posted but still doesnt work 100% properly. The code works allright almost all cases but still some cases get it wrong. I'm having trouble with the white pegs, im still having some extra white pegs in one case, for example if the code to guess is RYPG and i introduce RRRR it answer back 1 red flag and 1 white flag when it should say just 1 red flag. and if the code is RYPG and i introduce RRPP it answer back 2 red flags and 2 white flags when it should be just 2 red flags. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_STRING 4
#define SIZE_STRING_LONG 15

void randomSeed(){
    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) ); 
}

int randomM(int nMin, int nMax){
    return nMin + rand()%(nMax-nMin+1);
}


int main(){

randomSeed();

char szUser[SIZE_STRING_LONG];
char szP[6]={'Y','B','W','P','R','G'}, szComputer[SIZE_STRING_LONG] = {szP[randomM(0,5)], szP[randomM(0,5)], szP[randomM(0,5)], szP[randomM(0,5)], '\0'};
int counter=0;
int colour=0;
int position=0; 
char alreadyChecked[SIZE_STRING];


printf("\n\n MASTERMIND ");
printf("\n\n We'll play with this colours:");
printf("\n\n Y - Yellow    B - Blue     W - White");
printf("\n P - Purple    R - Red      G - Green");
printf("\n\n You have 8 changes to get t right. \n");           
printf("\n\n White flags indicate right colour in right position");
printf("\n\n Red flags indicate right colour in wrong position");

printf("\n\n Computer choses %s", szComputer); //check if the program works allright

do{
    counter++;
    position=0;
    colour=0;
    memset(alreadyChecked, 0, sizeof(alreadyChecked));
    printf("\n ===================================================\n");
    printf("\n Chance %d", counter);
    printf("\n\n Please enter your 4 colours choice");
    printf("\n (Please write capital letters without space  ");         
    scanf("%s",szUser);     

    if(strlen(szUser) != SIZE_STRING)
    {
        printf("\n\n Sorry you choose a wrong option.");
        counter--;
    } else {

            if(strcmp(szUser,szComputer))
            {
                printf("\n Wrong choice. Try again...");                    

                for (int u = 0; u < SIZE_STRING; u++)
                {
                    if (szUser[u] == szComputer[u])
                    {
                        position++;                             
                    }
                }

                if (position > 0 && position < 2)
                {
                    printf("\n\n You have %d red flag", position);
                }

                if (position > 1 )
                {
                    printf("\n\n You have %d red flags", position);
                }

                for (int u = 0; u < SIZE_STRING; u++)
                {

                    if (szUser[u] == szComputer[u])
                    {        
                        continue;
                    }

                        for (int c = 0; c < SIZE_STRING; c++)
                        {
                            if (!alreadyChecked[c] && szUser[u] == szComputer[c])
                            {
                                colour++;
                                alreadyChecked[c] = 1;

                                break; 
                            }
                        }
                }       



                if (colour > 0 && colour < 2)
                {
                    printf("\n\n You have %d white flag", colour);
                }

                if (colour > 1 )
                {
                    printf("\n\n You have %d white flags", colour);
                }

                if (colour == 0 && position == 0)
                {
                    printf("\n\n 0 white flags and 0 red flags");
                }
            }
        }

}while(strcmp(szUser,szComputer) && counter <=7);

if (strcmp(szUser,szComputer))
{
    printf("\n\n Sorry, you run out of chances...");
}   

if(!strcmp(szUser,szComputer))
    printf("\n\n Right combination !\n");

return 0;
}
```